# What is the equivalent of this CURL command in python?

Tags: python, authentication, kerberos

I am trying to connect to an API with `kerberos authentification`.

With `CURL` its just simple:

```sh
curl -k --negotiate -u : "https://MY-API-SERVER" -i
```

With `Python` I just can't find how to do the samething.

What I tried so far is:

```py
from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth, REQUIRED
kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=REQUIRED,force_preemptive=True)
r = requests.get("https://MY-API-SERVER", auth=kerberos_auth,verify=False, headers={'username':'xxxxx', 'password':'yyyyy'})
```

Comment: The whole purpose of Kerberos is to avoid to transmit passwords on-the-fly, in an unsecure way... so your headers don't make any sense. Unless Python has a concept of "headers" that is different from HTTP headers.

Comment: HTTP usually supports Kerberos auth through SPNEGO. Searching for `python SPNEGO` on StackOverflow yields a few answers, but none involve `HTTPKerberosAuth`...!